# Remove quotes around a word

Tags: php, regex

Sometimes I've got productnames with quotes around a certain word. Now I want to delete these quotes, but not the other quotes. For example:

> Sneakers 'Shuffles' Rock n' Beauty

The quotes around Shuffles need to be removed, but the quotes at n' may not be removed. Only the quotes around a word need to be removed.

Comment: `preg_replace("/['](\w+?)[']/",' ' ,$string);`

Comment: yah, you r right @Mariano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove quotes around a certain word use the following approach with `preg_replace` function:

```
$str = "Sneakers 'Shuffles' Rock n' Beauty";
$replaced = preg_replace("/['\"](\w+?)['\"]/", "$1", $str);

print_r($replaced);  "Sneakers Shuffles Rock n' Beauty"
```

Comment: I guess it's not possible with a name like Sneakers 'Shuffles Go' Rock n' Beauty?

Comment: what should be the result for `Sneakers 'Shuffles Go' Rock n' Beauty` ?

Comment: Sneakers Shuffles Go Rock n' Beauty. But I think that the regex can't recognize that these quotes belong to each other?

Comment: @Roger, your initial question is for *a certain word*. But now it's about a sequence of words. Secondly, it still can be achieved with regex

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Sneakers 'Shuffles' Rock n' Beauty Sneakers 'Shuffles' Rock n' Beauty";
$result_str = preg_replace("/'([\S]+)'/",'$1',$str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove quotes around the text by using this pattern:

```
<?php
    $string = "Sneakers 'Shuffles' Rock n' Beauty . Did't 'TEST'";
    $result = preg_replace("/['](\w+?)[']/",'$1' ,$string);
    echo $result;
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Sneakers Shuffles Rock n' Beauty . Did't TEST
```